# How to override existing CSS to let child <div> 1 has fixed width and child <div> has remaining width of parent?

Tags: css

I'm trying to write Firefox stylish css (**full screen width style**) for our StackExchange sites.

In the tagged question list page (eg: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java ), the HTML is like the following

```
<div class='question-summary'>
    <div class='statscontainer'>
        <div>n votes</div>
        <div>n answers</div>
        <div>n views</div>
    </div>
    <div class='summary'>
        <h3>Question title</h3>
        <div>question excerpt ...</div>
        <div>tag1 tag2 tagN </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The original CSS use fixed width on parent/child 1/child 2

```
<style>
    .question-summary
    {
        float: left;
        width: 730px;
        background-color: silver;
    }
    .statscontainer
    {
        float: left;
        width: 86px;
        margin-right: 8px;
        background-color: gray;
    }
    .summary
    {
        float: left;
        width: 635px;
        background-color: lightgray;
    }
</style>
```

Now I try to override CSS to let it **fit full screen width**

```
    .question-summary
    {
        float: left;
        width: 100% !important;    /* parent: full screen width */
        background-color: silver;
    }
    .statscontainer
    {
        float: left;
        width: 86px;    /* child 1: fixed width */
        margin-right: 8px;
        background-color: gray;
    }
    .summary
    {
        float: left;
        /*
        width: 80% !important;   <--- how to let child 2 has remaining width ?
        left: 95px;
        right: 0px;
        */
        background-color: lightgray;
    }
```

The question is, how to let child 2 has remaining width ? I know when using `<table>` to control layout, it is pretty easy.

```
<table style='width:100%'>
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor='gray' style='width:80px'>fixed width</td>
        <td bgcolor='lightgray'>automatically has remaining width</td>
    <tr>
</table>
```

**Edit**

According both @sandeep and @MrLister 's answers, it should override 3 CSS properties to get this work

```
.question-summary .summary {
    width: auto !important;      /* original = width: 735px; */

    float: none !important;      /* original = float: left; set to 'none' to get the 'overflow' property work */
    overflow: hidden !important; /* original = not set, default is visible */
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should reset the width to its initial value, which is `auto`.

Edit:
As you noted though, in order for `width:auto` to work, you should also reset the `float` property, otherwise the width won't take up the rest of the available space.

Comment: i tried `auto` before, in IE8 and Firefox, the width of child 2 is shrinked to it's minimal width.

Comment: `auto` is not working is because of the original CSS has defined `float: left`, so I need override `float` and `width` and `overflow` to get it work: `float: none !important; width: auto !important; overflow: hidden !important`.

Comment: You are right. Sorry I didn't notice that! I will edit my answer, for future reference.

Answer (score 4):

Write like this:

```
.question-summary
    {
        background-color: silver;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
    .statscontainer
    {
        float: left;
        width: 86px;    /* child 1: fixed width */
        margin-right: 8px;
        background-color: gray;
    }
    .summary
    {
        overflow:hidden;
        background-color: lightgray;
    }
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/pGu42/

Comment: That won't help, because if you don't set the widths explicitly, it will still take the width from the original stylesheet, `730px` for question-summary and `635px` for summary. The OP doesn't want that.

Comment: @MrLister read the question carefully OP not override the CSS. He have modify the css.

Comment: Nope. The original stylesheet is on the site and he cannot change that. The [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/) extension doesn't replace the original stylesheet, it only adds to it. So the only way to change a property is to _explicitly_ override it.

Comment: @sandeep, it's just interesting and working, how can [overflow](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp) affect the width ? @MrLister, thanks for your careful consideration, I will add `!important` in real environment, the demo code is only for standalone demo

Comment: Read this article about overflow:hidden trick http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/#making-room-for-floats

Comment: @MrLister, you're right, *The original stylesheet is on the site and I cannot change that*, and @ sandeep, sorry, i'm overriding, not modifing, sorry for my English, i can't distinguish the two word in this situation. I'll edit the question now